# Como inserir dados no banco (mysql) recebidos de um formulário HTML separado por virgulas?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite, eu vou receber uma informação vinda de um TEXTAREA html, e preciso receber isso no PHP e inserir essas informações no banco, como consigo fazer isso?

A informação vem do TEXTAREA da seguinte maneira:

0001, Aluno A, 10, 10, 20
0002, Aluno B, 8, 8, 16

as informações ja vem separadas por virgula, se fosse em um arquivo TXT ou CSV eu ja vi que conseguiria inserir através de um LOAD DATA mas no caso aqui um usuário vai digitar o texto e submeter através de um formulário HTML....

Comment: Dê uma olhada nisso http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php

Comment: poste o código, para verificarmos, sua pergunta não foi muito clara

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi a sua pergunta. Você quer separar essas informações para inserir no banco de dados.

Se no textarea a informação vier pulando linha igual está no seu exemplo, eu faria assim:

Utilizaria o explode para separa as informações, depois criaria uma string única e subiria no banco de dados os valores:

```
<?php 

    // aqui vem a informação do textarea
    $stringDoTextArea = $_POST['textArea'];

    // aqui eu inseri o <br /> para identificar que pulou linha
    $stringDoTextArea = nl2br($stringDoTextArea);

    // os dados agora são um array
    $dados = explode("<br />", $stringDoTextArea);

    // vamos criar a string que insere os dados no DB
    $stringDeInsercao = "INSERT INTO tabela(`campo1`, 'campo2', `campo3`, `campo4`) VALUES ";

    while($d = 0; $d < count($dados); $d++){

        // concatena linha por linha
        $dadoX = explode(",",$dados[$d]);
        $stringDeInsercao .= "('".$dadoX[0]."', '".$dadoX[1]."', '".$dadoX[2]."', '".$dadoX[3]."') ,";

    }

    // aqui eu retiro a ultima virgula
    $stringDeInsercao = substr($stringDeInsercao, 0, -1);

    // insere os dados de uma vez só
    mysqli_query($conexao, $stringDeInsercao);

?>
```

Isso é só um exemplo pois há varias formas de fazer.